# 'log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator' is not an attribute class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, c#-4.0, logging

I want to create a log text file for my mobile application.I am working on compact framework 3.5 and i chosen log4net for logging.I followed the below blog to create the Config.xml file and log file http://breathingtech.com/2009/using-apache-log4net-in-net-compact-framework-projects/ which runs without any error but not created any log file.See my Config.xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <!-- .NET application configuration file -->
    <configuration>
        <!-- This section contains the log4net configuration settings -->
        <log4net>
            <!-- Define some output appenders -->
            <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender" >
                <file value="log-file.txt" />
                <appendToFile value="true" />
                <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                     <conversionPattern value="%date [%-5level] - %message%newline" />
                </layout>
            </appender>
        <appender name="DebugAppender" type="log4net.Appender.DebugAppender">
          <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%-5level] - %message%newline" />
          </layout>
        </appender>
        <!-- Setup the root category, add the appenders
               and set the default level -->
            <root>
                <level value="ALL" />
          <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender" />
          <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
            </root>  
        </log4net>
    </configuration>
```

I added the below line under program.cs file

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));

string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0].FullyQualifiedName) + "\\Config.xml";
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            {
                log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new System.IO.FileInfo(path));
            }
Log.Info("Application startup");
```

Do my `Config.xml` is correct,i just copied the content from the above blog and i am getting the `Config.xml` path in program.cs.

Since the above setup not created `log-file.txt` and not logged the log.Info message,i googled and added the below line after the `using log4net.Config;`

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "../Config.xml", Watch = true)]
```

This give me an error "`'log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator' is not an attribute class`". Can any one help me in creating a log file in compact framework.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using following log4net configurations. I use this and it generates log file.

```
    <log4net>
        <!-- Define some output appenders -->
        <appender name="rollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
            <param name="File" value="log.txt"/>
            <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
            <param name="RollingStyle" value="Date"/>
            <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyy.MM.dd"/>
            <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="true"/>
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p - %m%n"/>
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <!-- Setup the root category, add the appenders and set the default priority -->
        <root>
            <priority value="ALL"/>
            <appender-ref ref="rollingFile"/>
        </root>
    </log4net>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your log4net config file you do not need to add the  `<configuration>` root tag. `<log4net>` should be the root. The `<configuration>` is the root tag if you are putting your config in the application config file or web config file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <log4net>
        <!-- Define some output appenders -->
        <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender" >
            <file value="log-file.txt" />
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                 <conversionPattern value="%date [%-5level] - %message%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
    <appender name="DebugAppender" type="log4net.Appender.DebugAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%-5level] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <!-- Setup the root category, add the appenders
           and set the default level -->
        <root>
            <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
        </root>  
    </log4net>
```